# Count em PostgreSQL usando OVER

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Eu tenho uma tabela de avaliação de professores e outra com as avaliações de alunos:

**tbl_professor**

```
id | nome
----------------------------
1  | José
2  | Maria
3  | Paulo
```

**tbl_avaliacao**

```
id | idprofessor | avaliacao | data
-------------------------------------
1  | 3           | R         | 2015-01-01
2  | 2           | B         | 2015-01-01
3  | 3           | B         | 2015-01-01
```

A avaliação do aluno pode ser R-Ruim, B-Bom, mas como poderia criar uma listagem como a de abaixo usando o OVER, pois ele não permite colocar um WHERE para esse tipo de filtragem?

```
avaliacoes_ruins | avaliacoes_boas
----------------------------------
1                | 2
```

Ou

```
professor |avaliacoes_ruins |avaliacoes_boas
---------------------------------------------
José      |0                |0
Maria     |0                |1
Paulo     |1                |1
```

Sei que o último caso seria possível fazer o SQL

```
SELECT
    nome,
    (SELECT (COUNT) FROM tbl_avaliacao WHERE idprofessor = tbl_professor.id AND avaliacao = 'R') AS avaliacoes_ruins,
    (SELECT (COUNT) FROM tbl_avaliacao WHERE idprofessor = tbl_professor.id AND avaliacao = 'B') AS avaliacoes_boas
FROM
    tbl_professor
```

Mas no caso acima o custo do SQL será alto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é restrito a PostgreSQL, mas eu faria desta forma:

Contagem de avaliações

```
professor |avaliacao |quantidade
--------------------------------
José      |B         |0
José      |R         |0
Maria     |B         |0
Maria     |R         |1
Paulo     |B         |1
Paulo     |R         |1
```

Com inner join, group by e count.

Se quiser realmente juntar em uma linha por professor, pode usar uma soma com UNION ALL, não sei se esta query funciona no PostreSQL sem adaptação:

```
SELECT nome, SUM(avaliacoes_ruins), SUM(avaliacoes_boas)
FROM (
    SELECT p.nome, COUNT(a.avaliação) AS avaliacoes_ruins, 0 AS avaliacoes_boas
    FROM tbl_professor p INNER JOIN tbl_avaliacao a ON a.idprofessor = p.id
    WHERE a. avaliação = 'R' GROUP BY p.nome, avaliacoes_boas
  UNION ALL
    SELECT p.nome, 0 AS avaliacoes_ruins, COUNT(a.avaliação) AS avaliacoes_boas
    FROM tbl_professor p INNER JOIN tbl_avaliacao a ON a.idprofessor = p.id
    WHERE a.avaliação = 'B' GROUP BY p.nome, avaliacoes_ruins
) tb_tmp
GROUP BY nome
```

Deve ter um custo menor que o da query que está na pergunta, principalmente para quantidade elevada de registros, pois não tem recursão. Pode ser necessário um alias para a subquery, não me lembro, mas usei `tb_tmp`.

Para juntar tudo em uma linha só precisa das duas queries com o union all sem o agrupamento por professor.

Não testei.

**Edição:** Esqueci de dizer: devem haver índices adequadamente definidos, do contrário, não haverá query que torne seu banco eficiente em termos de velocidade.